# Oracle 11: reclaim space after setting BLOBs to NULL

Tags: oracle

On this table that contains BLOBs and up to today filled up a 32GB tablespace, I removed a large percentage of BLOBs by setting them to NULL with an UPDATE statement (leaving the remaining columns untouched of course). No space was actually freed so I had to add a 2nd datafile, 4GB, in order to allow INSERT queries to work. I did a "alter table X move", no benefit. I did  a "alter table X shrink space", it actually increased the occupancy of the 2nd datafile and left the 1st one unaffected.

I found a [utility](https://oracle-base.com/dba/script.php?category=monitoring&file=ts_free_space.sql)  on the net that calculates how much space can be saved, and it gives me that the USERS ts has just 4004MB that can be freed, when I'd expect at least 10GB (4GB from the 2nd datafile that should be basically empty plus at least 6GB from the 1st datafile that was initially filled to capacity=32GB).

It seems impossible to free up space. Was setting to NULL a bad idea? Why is Oracle refusing to see any space as reclaimable?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_update_blob_reclaim_space.htm

> **Answer:**  The LOB/BLOB column still exists within the table blocks, and the data is still there.  It is only marked as unused.  To free up the space, use this command:
>
> ```
> alter table 
>    my_tab
> modify lob
>    event_data
> (shrink space);
> ```
>
> Remember, you must shrink lob or move, after updating column as null or empty_blob.